# Make remote Git track a remote branch from another repo

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging

I have a repo `A` with a branch `a` and repo `B` with branch `b`.

I would like to make the branch `B:b` track `A:a` (with a local copy of either of these branches if necessary). Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the local B repo:

1. First setup a remote to **A** repositoy named *upstream* (or any other name you prefer):

   ```
   git remote add upstream <A remote address>
   ```
2. Make branch **b** track **a**:

   check to see if you have a local **b** branch:

   ```
   git branch --list
   ```

   - if you already have got a local **b**:

     ```
     git branch -u upstream/a b
     ```
   - if you does not have a local **b**:

     ```
     git checkout -b b upstream/a
     ```

Now in the **b** Branch of **B** repo if you do `git fetch`, `git pull` and `git push` it will sync against **A:a** and for syncing against original **B:b** run `git pull origin b` for example to pull.